# Netbeans will not Deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, servlet-container

I am struggling to get my Netbeans IDE to deploy my Java Web Project to a tomcat server (I normally use Eclipse).  I have setup the tomcat server (7.0.55) within Netbeans (8.0.1) and can start and stop the server.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to deploy any applications I receive this error:

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\kevin.bowersox\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FKEVIN%7E1.BOW%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2F1%2Fcontext882537679043940070.xml&path=/WebApplication1
Connection timed out: connect
C:\Users\kevin.bowersox\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1070: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 minutes 0 seconds)
```

I have checked all of the tomcat logs (catalina.out, localhost, etc), but they do not reveal what is causing this error.  I can see that the server startup occurs in the logs, but the deployment fails.  At the moment I am only deploying a very simple Java web application (basically what gets created initially).

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me where to find more debugging output?  I have googled this issue for the past few hours with no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your proxy settings? As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21137287/634958

Comment: Also try looking into IDE logs!

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR Where are the IDE logs located?

Comment: i think its in View -> IDE Log

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR It was the proxy settings! Thanks so much man, seven hours to find that check box.  Ugggghhhh.

Answer (score 0):

The answer linked in the comment by @S1LENWARRIOR worked for me, even though I wasn't getting any error messages in the logs (just a timeout).

> Did you check your proxy settings? As mentioned here: stackoverflow.com/q/21137287/634958

On MacOS (NetBeans 8.2), I got to these proxy settings by going to "NetBeans > Preferences..." and it's in the first "General" pane that's already open by default in that window. Changed it to "No proxy" and deployments work now.